# Voltage reduction issues in an existing circuit

Tags: voltage

[image: Boxmag wiring diagram]

In the above diagram, I am trying to reduce the input voltage of 7.4v to no more than 3v, which is the maximum rating for the M2 motor. This is for a boxmag used with an Airsoft gun, specifically an M16 style 5,000 round boxmag. The idea is to operate the gun and the boxmag off the trigger switch of the gun. I have had this circuit in use in other boxmags, but recent events has shown that a potential problem with overheating of the resistor can occur and thus result in frying the resistor.

My current components are listed below,
Motor (M2)
Diode (1N4001) (Had to replace the original Schottky diode)
Resistor 5 ohm, 1/2 Watt, 5% tolerance
Switch DPDT

The switch must be able to achieve two modes of operation, 1] constant power for priming the boxmag, and 2] selective power for operation off the gun's trigger switch. The diode acts as a control gate to prevent damage to the motor, or that is how I understand it anyways.

I ran some calculations using available data to determine the resistor's rating, these are the calculations below,

[image: Formulas]

The motor has these statistics,
Voltage range: 1.5 to 3 volts
Current: 0.18 to 0.25 amps w/o load, 0.70 amps +/- 15% at max efficiency
Output: 0.31 watts

If I understood everything correctly, the device (M2) has a resistance of 10.57 ohms, which when entered into the formulas and calculated out, should have brought me to 2.37 volts at the motor, but since the circuit keeps frying the resistor, I'm not so sure anymore.

Therefore, my question is, how can I address this issue such that I will achieve the correct results without risking frying the resistor?

Any assistance to achieve my goals is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Stack exchange doesn't use PHPbb type markup, there's a button with an image insert (or Ctrl-G) where you can upload an image from your PC if you want to edit your question. I was about to try editing it but the Photobucket links don't seem to be working.

Comment: Those links don't work so we can't tell what is being asked.  Closing.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know how that worked, most forum sites I'm familiar with do not have a direct upload ability. I have fixed the issue and added some additional information, please release my hold status. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing at your schematic, but if I assume you simply place the resistor in series with the motor then a quick calculation shows that your resistor is severely underrated:

To drop the voltage from 7.4 to 3 volt there must be 4.4 volts across the resistor. Using the formula P = U² / R it follows that P = 3.9 Watt, way too much for your 5 ohm, 1/2 Watt resistor. It may be okay for short bursts (e.g. trigger pulls) but for repeated / long press it will overheat.

Also note that the DC resistance you measure across your motor with a multimeter is useless. When a motor runs it draws less current due to back EMK. The only proper way is to measure the current while the motor is running. You will also find that there is a non-linear relationship between voltage and current; so you have to experiment to find the proper value.

Comment: Your point about long bursts makes sense, I believe this may be part of the problem as the player whose equipment I am attempting to repair has a bad habit of laying on his trigger and not letting up. However, I have this same set up in other boxmags and have not experienced any similar issues, which is what confuses me. I have been experimenting with different resistors this morning and it seems the higher the resistance, the less likely the motor is to operate. I can get it to work with a 10 ohm resistor, but a 100 ohm or higher results in no motor operation.

Comment: I, unfortunately, do not have any other resistors in between these values, but several over the 100 ohms and none of them worked either. Additionally, I placed the negative lead of my multimeter on the negative motor connection and the positive lead between the resistor and the motor, when I would activate the motor, the meter would begin climbing until it passed the 20 volt mark I had it set at, which I am guessing is the point you were making about reading voltage while the motor is operating, it is kind of useless, or I'm I connecting things incorrectly to get an accurate reading.

Comment: I always get a little confused when it come to placing the leads for a proper reading. Hopefully the new images and information clear things up and make it easier to understand. Thank you for your input, it is helpful.

Comment: 20 volt? That's odd... Anyway, I should start with a 10 ohm, **5 Watt** resistor; if the motor runs too slow, go for a bit lower value (8.2, 6.8, 4.7 etc. you better order a bunch of them). And oh, you can get rid of the diode; it serves no purpose here. The motor doesn't run at 100 ohm because the current is then too low.

Comment: After reading your response, I did some research to better understand your comments; after all, I'm still a novice when it comes to electronics, circuits, etc. You stated I was dissipating about 3.9 watts, which is something I had not considered when calculating for my resistor. Based on that, I purchased several 10 watt and higher resistors and began experimenting. My results lead me to install two 10 ohm 10 watt resistors and tap the middle point to create a voltage divider to supply the motor with the necessary voltage. ...

Comment: Sounds like a good start. You can probably do without the second resistor as the motor will function as the lower 'leg' of the voltage divider; all that resistor will do now is heat up and drain your batteries faster.

Comment: This is not my preferred method, I would rather have used one resistor; unfortunately, my local electronics parts supply store is temporarily out of business as they had an electrical fire, the irony is not lost on this one. Therefore, Radio Shack was my only other local source for parts and I was limited by their stock on hand. After assembling this circuit, I tested it and the voltage still spiked a bit from time to time, but never higher than 6 or 7 volts. It generally stayed below the 3 volt mark, which is what I am aiming for; therefore, I felt it was acceptable. ...

Comment: Final testing in the gun/boxmag combination went well, no overheating or other issues, except a jam in the feed, but that is an unrelated issue. As to the diode, It was in the original wiring harness, so I left it because if I understand its purpose correctly, it is a safety mechanism to prevent reverse power flow, so the motor never turns in the opposite direction. To do so would lock the gears in the boxmag, if not destroy them completely as they are only plastic. I tried using just the one resistor, but the voltage continued to spike extremely high, which is why I went with two in the end.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for all your help, I now have a better understanding of the situation and can correct my wiring diagram for future use. I will be replacing the two resistors with a 5 ohm 5 watt or higher in the future, and now I also know to take wattage (energy dissipation) into consideration when performing future calculations for such situations. Again, thank you for all your help, it is appreciated.